# How can I make multiple divs move?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have two squares bouncing around in a box. The squares are an HTML div created using my createBlock function and put into global variables. One of the squares moves as intended while the other one doesn't move at all. Both squares are created exactly the same, the only difference being the name of the variable they are held in and the ID of the divs. Right now, only the obstacle moves.

How come only one div moves?

```js
var player;
var obstacle;

function createBlock(startXSpd, startYSpd, color, id, target) {
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML += "<div  class='smallRectangle' id='" + id + "'></div>";
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.top = ((Math.random() * 600)) + "px"
  elem.style.left = ((Math.random() * 700)) + "px";
  elem.style.height = "25px";
  elem.style.width = "25px";
  elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
  elem.xSpd = startXSpd;
  elem.ySpd = startYSpd;
  return elem;
}

window.onload = function() {
  player = createBlock(2, 2, "green", "player", "bigRectangle");
  obstacle = createBlock(2, 2, "red", "obstacle", "bigRectangle");

  var move = setInterval(function() {
    bounce(obstacle);
    moveBlock(obstacle);
    bounce(player);
    moveBlock(player);
  }, 10);
}

window.onload = function() {
  player = createBlock(2, 2, "green", "player", "bigRectangle");
  obstacle = createBlock(2, 2, "red", "obstacle", "bigRectangle");
  box = createBlock(2, 2, "blue", "box", "bigRectangle");

  var move = setInterval(function() {
    bounce(obstacle);
    moveBlock(obstacle);
    bounce(player);
    moveBlock(player);
    bounce(box);
    moveBlock(box);
  }, 10);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=“bigRectangle></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should share your HTML as well

Comment: I've moved your code into a demo snippet. Please revise it to show the problem.